# How is "integers ${\rm mod} ~n$ under addition" a cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups

I'm new to abstract algebra and group theories. I'm trying to study cyclic groups. For example, i know that integers $\mathbb Z+$ is a cyclic group since it is generated by $1$ (its additive identity, additive inverse and multiples).

But if we take integers mod $n$ under addition, It will be a finite cyclic group:

$\{0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5,\ldots,n-1\}$

Now I know that integers $\pmod{n}$ under addition is a cyclic group since it is also generated by $1$. I also know that:

$n\equiv 0\pmod{n}$

$n+1\equiv 1\pmod{n}$

$n-1\equiv -1\pmod{n}$

But as I know, somehow, group generated by $1$ repeats itself and cycles through certain numbers:

$\ldots-2,  -1,  0,  1,  2,\ldots , n-1 , n , n+1 , n+2,\ldots, 2n-1, 2n, 2n+1, \ldots$

How does this group cycle? At which number does the group repeat itself?

Thank you!

Comment: $1+1+...+1+1$ with $n+1$ terms is again $1$.

Comment: @orole But shouldn't group have identities, inverses and multiples of 1? (I'm sorry if i misunderstood something).

Comment: The identity is $0$, the inverse of $a$ is $n-a$, the multiples of $1$ are $1+1+...+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cyclic group is defined as a group which can be generated by a single element.

For example, let $G = \Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z = \lbrace 0, 1, 2, 3, 4\rbrace$ with addition. Then

$$\begin{align}
1 &\equiv 1 \bmod 5\\
1 + 1 &\equiv 2 \bmod 5\\
1+1+1 &\equiv 3 \bmod 5\\
1+1+1+1 &\equiv 4 \bmod 5\\
1+1+1+1+1 &\equiv 0 \bmod 5
\end{align}$$

and since these are all of the elements of $G$, we conclude that this group is cyclic, and is generated by $1$, which can be written $G = \langle 1\rangle$ (although this requires some context, simply writing $\langle 1\rangle$ doesn't give enough information).

The way the elements cycle comes from the way the group $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is defined. The "number" in the set $\lbrace 0, 1, 2, \dots, n-1\rbrace$ actually refers to the remainder when an integer is divided by $n$. For example, in the case $n = 5$, we see that $23 = 4 \times 5 + 3$, so $23 \equiv 3 \bmod 5$. Since the only possible candidates for remainders after dividing by $5$ are the numbers $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ (convince yourself of this; for example, if I wrote $23 = 3 \times 5 + 8$, I could take another $5$ from the $8$ and have $23 = 3 \times 5 + 5+ 3 = 4\times 5 + 3$), these are the elements of the group.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you said yourself that $0$ and $n$ are the same mod $n$.  So the group "cycles" when you reach $n$, since that's the same as going back to $0$.  In other words, if you list the elements you get by repeatedly adding $1$, they go: $$0,  1,  2,  \dots  , n-1 , 0 , 1 , 2, \dots , n-1, 0, 1, \dots$$

Comment: Thank you a lot! But is the group cyclic because it is generated by 1, or because numbers wrap around due to modulo? Thanks again!

Comment: The group is cyclic because it is generated by $1$.  That's the definition of "cyclic" (generated by a single element).  The group $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic too, even though its elements don't "wrap around".